# How do I merge two C header files, such that re- #defines are removed?

Tags: text-processing, c

Supposing I have:

sdk.h:

```
#define foo 1
#define bar 1
```

app.h:

```
#define foo 0
```

How can I generate a merged.h that looks like this, given I want app.h to redefine anything already defined in sdk.h:

```
#define foo 0
#define bar 1
```

One approach might be "don't do this, just let the preprocessor do it for you". I've tried that and it's not going to work for my situation I don't think. I'm really looking for an approach using a basic shell script.

Comment: Just include `app.h` after including `sdk.h`. If that doesn't work, then please update your question what exactly it is that goes wrong.

Comment: If it is only for handling the #define -s, then it could be easily implemented in some shellscript or maybe in awk/python/anything. However, if the first header uses some #define in it, then the result will be a lot of mystical errors. Furthermore, for anything more complex analyse, you need to essentially re-write the C preprocessor, which is not a funny task.

Comment: does `sort -k1,2 -u app.h sdk.h` give you the correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the contents in the header files is not important, you could do something like this:

```
$ awk '/#define/{a[$2]=$3; next}1;END{for(i in a){print "#define",i,a[i]}}' sdk.h app.h 
#define foo 0
#define bar 1
```

Note that any lines not containing `#define` will be printed first.